# How to make new line from a xml response string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xml

I get my data from an API, which return XML, I already convert it to json because I use angularjs, the field that I need, store Songs Lyrics and it used this symbol  `↵` when ever it should go to new line.
for example :

```
You shout it loud↵But I can’t hear a word you say↵I’m talking loud, not saying much↵↵I’m criticized but all your bullets ricochet↵You shoot me down, but I get up
```

example above, is something that I get when I use `console.log()` but when I show this field to my HTML page, its just string with no `↵` in it. I don't know why it not show in HTML, and if its something to make new line, it's not happening.

I was thinking to replace `↵` with `<br />` is it possible? I will be appreciate it if you guys can help me with that.

UPDATE :
I use angularjs and fill the model with lyric and show it with {{lyric}} in my html

but as you can see in picture, when I use console.log($scope.lyric) string is formated well, but when I show the same model in HTML, its like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out, I let you know how it works in case of anyone else face with same problem :

when I show lyric like this :

```
<p>{{lyric}}</p>
```

it ignored my new lines. but when I use this :

```
<pre>{{lyrics}}</pre>
```

it works!

Answer (score 1):

Simple regexr string replace should take care of it:

```js
var str = 'You shout it loud↵But I can’t hear a word you say↵I’m talking loud, not saying much↵↵I’m criticized but all your bullets ricochet↵You shoot me down, but I get up';

var formatted = str.replace(/↵/ig, "<br/>\n");

console.log(formatted);
document.write(formatted);
```

The regexr finds everything that matches the character between the `/` signs and replaces them with a standard newline `\n` and a HTML breakline tag `<br/>`.

The `i` and `g` flags mean `Case Insensitive` and `Search Global` respectively.

`Case Insensitive` catches the characters even if they are in a different case. `Search Global` means that if you input a multi line string, then it will replace on all lines and not just on the first.

Comment: Thank you, your method is right and should work, but I don't know why in my html its not show new lines, even in my console log is formated well and it display in new lines, I suspect maybe in angularjs things are different, I fill the model with lyrics and display it like {{lyric}} , but its not formated and it not show new lines at all

Comment: I just update my question and add a photo from my console, any idea?

Comment: It seems to not be adding the `<br/>` tags. Can you show the code you use to modify the string?

Comment: $scope.myLyric=vm.lyric.response.replace(/↵/ig, "<br/>\n");

Comment: vm.lyric.response contain the lyric text

Comment: What does this give you?: `var test = vm.lyric.response.replace(/↵/ig, "<br/>\n"); console.log(test); $scope.myLyric=test;`

Comment: console.log(test) give me the same result with my screen shot, it formatted well, but the problem is when I display $scope.myLyric to my html using {{myLyric}} , it is not formatted anymore ,no new lines in html.

Comment: Try posting your controllers source code here so view can find the error